# How can I export all files in a Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have several hundred source files in a single directory some of which are part of a VS2010 project. I want to export only those files that are listed in the Solution Explorer of that project.

It would be nice to have a solution that does not use plugins or macros as I am not very familiar with VS2010.

Comment: You could only ask this question if you don't use source control or it is not integrated with VS.  That's a really bad practice.  Fix that first, the rest is simple.

Comment: No, all the files are version controlled. I am trying to create a "bare bones" framework from a much larger codebase. The code is pretty tightly integrated with VS and this is precisely what I want to change.